# SOAP DebuggingInfo header not being returned. Breaks strict WSDL interpretation?

Tags: soap-api, wsdl

SOAP responses to the upsert verb now include the LimitInfoHeader header but not the DebuggingInfo header.  This causes SOAP clients who interpret the WSDL strictly to fail with the exception that the sequence of the headers is violated.  Can the response with the LimitInfoHeader be turned off, or can the response be configured to include DebuggingInfo header?

This is for the Enterprise WSDL API 38.

Comment: I see in the v38.0 Enterprise and Partner WSDLs that both the `DebuggingInfo` and `LimitInfoHeader` are expected as output headers to the upsert operation. What are you sending in for the `DebuggingHeader` on the request? It's been some time since the DebuggingInfo header response was returned. You only really see it in the older Apex WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

Set request header, DebuggingHeader/debugLevel to one of applicable logging level should work. 
https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/previous/intcs_gs/ICSSF/GUID-27ECEC42-E732-46C2-964A-E872A0078771.htm#ICSSF-GUID-27ECEC42-E732-46C2-964A-E872A0078771